# Can't allocate memory for double linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

```
    DList CreateDList( DList L ){
    L = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    L = malloc (sizeof( struct DListStruct));
    if( L == NULL )
        FatalError( "Out of memory!" );
    L->DHeader= NULL;
    L->DFooter= NULL;
    return L;
}
```

This is my function to create the list i am sure something not right here but when i try to put something in the list i get a segmentation fault error so i figured that it is because of the wrong memory allocation in the insertion functions

```
    DPosition I=L->DHeader;
    DPosition T=0;
    int Count=0;
    while(Count!=i){
        I=Advance(I);
        T=I->Prev;
        Count++;    
    }
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->Element =X;
    struct Node *next = T->Next;

    T->Next=new_node;
    new_node->Prev=T;
    new_node->Next=next;
    next->Prev=new_node;
```

this is the insertion function it suposed to insert but just get a segmentation fault I browser the internet to the memory allocation but i am quite confused.
by the way this is my main function

```
int main(){
    DList L=CreateDList(L);
    InsertDListIth(2,0,L);
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least this code snippet     L = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    L = malloc (sizeof( struct DListStruct)); does not make any sense.

Comment: i tought because i have to struct one node(element,next,prev) and other for the list containing the dheader and dfooter that i should just do that but like i said i know lot of things wrong but can't just tell what

Comment: One variable can only hold one address at a time. If you assign a second, the first one is lost and you will never be able to free that memory

Comment: When `i == 0`, there is no previous node `T`, and `T->Next` will segfault. We don't know what `Advance(I)` does, but if `i` is greater than the number of elements in the list, that might cause problems, too. You can find out what happens exactly by running your code in a debugger.

Comment: `DList CreateDList( DList L )` You don't use `L` here. Also it is considered bad practice to hide pointers in typedefs.

Comment: @Gerhardh can you explain about more what you talking with the typedefs i am a  beginner trying to learn so might just understant that

Comment: Please [edit] and post a [mcve]. And before you might want to read this: [ask]

Comment: In your code, `DList` must be defined as a pointer type. (Generally you should show your type definitions to avoid guessing.) In the parameter list it is not visible that it is a pointer. That is bad. You should always see what you are dealing with.